# NSString Remove characters from email address

Tags: iphone

Using Iphone sdk 4.3 if i have an NSString like this

name@domain.com

How do i strip everything after the '@' so i am just left with 'name'.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split the string;

```
NSArray *parts= [emailAddress componentsSeparatedByString: @"@"];
```

and use the first part of the resultant array.

Answer (score 0):

First use the - (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString - Function of the NSString Object to get the Position of the @-Charakter.

Then use - (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)aRange. aRange needs two Arguments first one is starting Element and the number of following Elements, so the first Argument is 0 and the second is the Position of the @. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

tech74's answer is good. :)

Though I also have one approach on this one.

```
NSString *emailAddress = @"name@domain.com";
NSString *name = [emailAddress substringToIndex:[emailAddress rangeOfString:@"@"].location];
//to check:
NSLog(@"Name: %@", name);
```

Hope this is okay.
If you will have a good use of the "domain" part, tech74's answer is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *emailAddress = @"name@Domain.com";
NSString *name = [emailAddress substringToIndex:[emailAddress rangeOfString:@"@"].location];
NSString *doman = [emailAddress substringFromIndex:[emailAddress rangeOfString:@"@"].location+1];
NSLog(@"Name: %@", name);
NSLog(@"Doman: %@", [doman lowercaseString]);

Output
Name: name
doman: domain.com
```

**In case you need to restrict all upper case for domain**